# Git can't find sha1 — Can I discard the history and just start fresh?

Tags: git, github

I've read countless Q&As here about recovering a broken git repository.

`git gsck`, `git cat-file -s <sha1>`, `git gc --aggressive`, `git repack -a -f` and on and on.  I've even tried cloning again from the remote (github).  I've tried them all and still get corrupt and missing files (yes, even on github).

Can you help me just start fresh?  If I don't care about history till now, what is the command that goes nuclear on anything in history and starts fresh?

Here's one recent attempt:

```
~> git repack -a -f
Counting objects: 13150, done.
error: unable to find 25cf6740ca26d90a932e59e1337425d7f227a8a8
error: unable to find 26cf4dfed14d3230854008c483982b0b8727ccd1
error: unable to find 41dc657cfca10511a2351b18aaff054504fb9c31
error: unable to find 8bb2dff3a758d12603f4340d4da7eb6c3144749d
error: unable to find cf59f4bbfacb6ac791e3aa1f0c39b3e8d468964b
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13041/13041), done.
fatal: unable to read 26cf4dfed14d3230854008c483982b0b8727ccd1
```

Comment: How many branches do you have? Can you see them all with `git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate`? Can you switch between them with `git checkout <branch>`?

Comment: Are you then able to pick a branch and do `git whatchanged` and go all the way back through history? If so, while still in the pager you could do `/25cf67|26cf4d|41dc65|8bb2df|cf59f4` to see if these are commits or files (trees aren't shown here). Maybe they're all in very recent commits, and you could just reset back before them so you don't have to lose *everything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir clean_repo
cd clean_repo
git init
cp -r ../bad_repo/. .
git add
git commit
```

This will make a new repo, then copy files from old repo (minus the `.git`). To "fix" the GitHub repo

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:antirez/redis.git
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Do I have to make a new github repository as well?  Or can I connect to the existing project still?